# run macro to an entire column

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

working on this macro on a dependent drop down menu

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$M$10" Then
        Range("O10").Value = "--select--"
    End If
End Sub
```

I need to run this macro for all the cells in the column. It just work in the first cell

Can anyone help me please?
thanks!

Comment: due to `Target.Address = "$M$10"` this code runs only on cell M10 it cannot run on the first cell. Note that there are several good tutorials about dpendent drop boxes. Did you check one out?

Comment: The dependent drop down menu is working well... the purpose of the macro is to reset the filter in column C any time I make any change to the filter in column B. I am now using Target. Column = B. Any cell modified in column B fire the change in column C but only for the first cell. How can I make sure that if I make that a change in B1 resets filter on C1, B2 on C2, B3 on C3 and so on? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `Application.Intersect` in combination with `.Offset()` instead of the `Target.Address` method.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B"))  'find all cells that were changed in column B

    If AffectedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'exit if nothing in column B was changed

    Application.EnableEvents = False  'make sure our value change doesn't trigger another Worksheet_Change event (endless loop)
    On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS  'make sure events get enabled even if an error occurs

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In AffectedRange.Cells  'loop through all changed cells in column B
        Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Value = ""  'move from B one column to the right and reset value
    Next Cell

ENABLE_EVENTS: 'in case of error enable events and report the error
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

This will observe column B and delete the value in C whenever a cell in B was changed.